SIM7600CE-T: MQTT communication: why is there a required length for command AT+CMQTTSUB?
I use SIM7600CE-T (TEL0124) to connect to my MQTT server.
I have a question about the SIM7600CE-T's command "AT+CMQTTSUB". I sucessfully use this command to read messages sent in the MQTT server, but I do not understand why this command needs a <req_length> input.
In the datasheet page 360 says (Among other information):

AT+CMQTTSUB Subscribe a message to server
<req_length> -> The length of input topic data. The message topic
should be UTF-encoded string. The range is from 1 to 1024 bytes.

in practice, I need to do:
//To subscribe to a topic and receive the messages (no polling):
AT+CMQTTSUBTOPIC=0,6,0\r 
Replies and wayts with:>

Now I send the topic name of 6 chars :newtop
Replies:OK

//subscribe to message server, define the length of chars for "input topic data"
AT+CMQTTSUB=0,3,0\r
Replies and wayts with:>

Send something with 3 chars: hia
//you are now subscribed.

So why do I need to send some random 3-char data (input topic data)? What is the use for it?

Because that's the way the people that designed it wrote it.

I believe the idea is that you can add a length to AT+CMQTTSUB if you only want to subscribe to one topic (you don't need the AT+CMQTTSUBTOPIC). For multiple topics you send multiple AT+CMQTTSUBTOPICs followed by AT+CMQTTSUB=<client_index> (no quantity included, so no request for additional data). The MQTT subscribe packet can contain multiple topics, so this method provides a simple way to send one topic, whilst still allowing multiple topics to be requested in one SUBSCRIBE packet.
